# how to return true or false from Angularfire2 facebook Authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, angularfire2

Ok so I'm pretty new to `AngularFire2` and `Angular2` in general, I'm learning the authentication method that `AngularFire2` provides.

So far I have successfully implemented logging in with `Facebook`, my code currently resides in a `service`.

So the code is simple (May look disgusting to you), I login via `Facebook` retrieve the users access token, and their facebookId, make a call to Facebook graph and retrieve Firstname, Lastname, Gender, Email etc then save this data within `Firebase` this is my code for doing the above:

```
loginWithFacebook(): FirebaseListObservable<string> {

  return FirebaseListObservable.create(obs => {
      this.af.auth.login({
          provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
          method: AuthMethods.Popup,
          scope: ['public_profile']
      }).then((authState: any) => {

      let userRef = this.af.database.object('/users/' + authState.uid); // get user profile

       userRef.subscribe(user => {

       let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/${user.facebookId}?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email&access_token=${user.accessToken}`;

       this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {

          let result = response.json()
             userRef.update({
               first_name: result.first_name,
               last_name: result.last_name,
               gender: result.gender,
               email_address: result.email,
               facebookId: user.facebookId
              })
            })
         })

          obs.next(userRef);

        }).catch(err => {
            obs.throw(err)
        });
    });
```

I call this from my `login.component` as shown:

```
 loginFacebook() {
       this.loginSubscription = this.service.loginWithFacebook().subscribe(data => {
          console.log('after finish', data);  
        });
    }
```

Issue I have is I want to capture if the login with facebook fails or passes I've tried populating the `Observable` within the Service method, however when I console.log 'after finish', data I see the following:

[image]

Can someone shed any light into how I go about returning true / false from this method? If anyone can see a cleaner way of doing this I would be highly appreciative.

Comment: please don't ask your questions twice! http://stackoverflow.com/q/41974101/3631348

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test right now, you could do it like this:

```js
loginWithFacebook(): Observable<boolean> {

   return this.af.auth.login({
          provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
          method: AuthMethods.Popup,
          scope: ['public_profile']
      })
      .map((authState: any) => {
         if (!authState) return false;

         let userRef = this.af.database.object('/users/' + authState.uid); // get user profile

         userRef.subscribe(user => {

            let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/${user.facebookId}?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email&access_token=${user.accessToken}`;

            this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {

               let result = response.json();
               userRef.update({
                  first_name: result.first_name,
                  last_name: result.last_name,
                  gender: result.gender,
                  email_address: result.email,
                  facebookId: user.facebookId
               })
            })
         })

         return true;    
      }).catch(err => {
         return Observable.of(false);
      });
}

loginFacebook() {
   this.loginSubscription = this.service.loginWithFacebook().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('after finish', data);  
   });
}
```

Comment: Just tried this: currently getitng the following errors: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<FirebaseAuthState>'. and Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: See your other question, lets discuss in only one thread! there it is splitted into separate functions and subscriptions..