# AngularFire2 Login Logout Subscribe to Auth issue - Angular2

Tags: angular, authentication, angularfire2

Ok so I've been banging my head against the wall for half a day trying to resolve this, reason I haven't as of yet is due to my level of knowledge with `AngularFire2` and `Angular2` is somewhat beginner.

I have an application, a simple login form which uses `AngularFire2` connects to `Facebook`, retrieves the users `Access Token` and `Facebook Id` and then calls the `Facebook Graph API` which returns firstname, lastname, gender, email etc.

As shown here:

```
loginWithFacebook(): FirebaseListObservable<string> {

    return FirebaseListObservable.create(obs => {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup,
            scope: ['public_profile']
        }).then((authState: any) => {

            let authSubscription = this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {

             if (auth == null) return;

                let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/${auth.facebook.uid}?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email&access_token=${authState.facebook.accessToken}`;

                this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
                    let user = response.json()

                    this.af.database.object('/users/' + authState.uid).update({
                        first_name: user.first_name,
                        last_name: user.last_name,
                        display_name: auth.facebook.displayName,
                        gender: user.gender,
                        email_address: auth.facebook.email,
                        accessToken: authState.facebook.accessToken,
                        facebook_Id: auth.facebook.uid,
                    })
                },
                    err => {
                        obs.next(false);
                    });

            });

            authSubscription.unsubscribe();

            obs.next(true);

        }).catch(err => {
            obs.next(false);
        });
    });

}
```

`Facebook Id` = Comes from `auth`
`Access Token` = Comes from `authState`

I then save the information returned from the `Facebook Graph API` to `Firebase`.

Now here comes the issue, as you can see inside the function specified above, I have subscribed to the `auth` method, this allows me to access the `Facebook Id` and the `Access Token` which is required to call `Facebook Graph API`

In the navigation of my application I have a logout button.  When the user clicks this button I call

```
this.af.auth.logout();
```

Once I've pressed logout, my function specified above will be called due to being subscribed to the change of `auth`, I've placed an if statement inside to check if auth is null, if so return which is working - Seems a bit hacky to me.

If I then try and sign back in, the url for calling `Facebook Graph API` fails on `${auth.facebook.uid}` which states it's `undefined`, which I'm not entirely sure why this would fail because to me it's classed as a new login so the method should run from start to finish again.

Now my question is this:

How can I get around subscribing to the `auth` within my Login with facebook method? and still access the `Facebook Id` and `Access Token`

I'm trying to figure out a way whereby the method will work for two scenarios which are:

1. User already exists in the database
2. User does not exist so its a fresh signup.

The logout and Sign Up/Login should both be isolated from one another and not interfere with one another responsibilities.

If anyone can share any knowledge or suggest a much cleaner way of doing this I would highly appreciate it.

**Update**

I've created a repository on `Github` which is a cut down version of my application and it shows the error I'm experiencing.

[Repo](https://github.com/Atkinson88/test-application)

To replicate:

Inside the `login.service` loginWithFacebook method you will see this line of code:

```
if (auth.facebook.uid == null) return;
```

comment this out and follow the steps below.

1. Login with facebook on the signup page
2. signout using the logout button
3. Sign back in with facebook straight after logging out

You will notice first time logging in it works, as soon as you signout and sign back in with facebook the graph API will fail due to `auth.facebook.uid` being undefined.

Now Ideally I do not want to subscribe to the auth event reason being is because we will be implementing signin with Google and email and password.

The only place I would like to subscribe to the `auth` event would be inside the nav bar which changes the menu navigation when the user becomes authorised.

NOTE: this is linked to a test account on firebase.  Once this issue has been resolved the test account will be deleted. So all account information that has been used to test this will be deleted.

**Final Update**

Ok so I’ve decided to open a bounty on this to help find a solution.

The only way I can see this working is having one login page, this login page will cater for new and existing user, if the user logs in with Facebook if they’re new then call Facebook Graph API retrieve information about them and then save it, if they’re existing then don’t call the Facebook Graph API.

How I expect this to work:

New User:

```
1.  User navigates to website
2.  Signs in with Facebook
3.  Popup appears
4.  Users grants the permissions I’ve requested
5.  Callback to website <- at this point I have access to users Facebook Id and accessToken via the auth
6.  Call Facebook Graph API retrieve first_name, last name etc passing in users Facebook Id and accessToken
7.  Then save the information returned from Facebook Graph to Firebase
```

Existing user

If the user has already signed up using Facebook then when he / she signs in I don’t want to call the Facebook Graph API, the call to the Graph is only required once for new accounts.

Also the repo is still available.

Error printed to console, after registering for the first time, logging out, logging in:

[image]

AngularFire2 package json

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.7",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "angularfire2",
        "name": "angularfire2",
        "rawSpec": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
        "spec": ">=2.0.0-beta.7 <3.0.0",
        "type": "range"
      },
      "/Users/Scott/Desktop/test-application-master 2"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "angularfire2@>=2.0.0-beta.7 <3.0.0",
  "_id": "angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/angularfire2",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.9.1",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/angularfire2-2.0.0-beta.7.tgz_1484315670561_0.09154823864810169"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "davideast",
    "email": "dceast@gmail.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.10.8",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "angularfire2",
    "name": "angularfire2",
    "rawSpec": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "spec": ">=2.0.0-beta.7 <3.0.0",
    "type": "range"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/angularfire2/-/angularfire2-2.0.0-beta.7.tgz",
  "_shasum": "ce4f98467c5a8b2cc1dfd607fda718aee8d64521",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.7",
  "_where": "/Users/Scott/Desktop/test-application-master 2",
  "author": {
    "name": "jeffbcross,davideast"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "<p align=\"center\">   <h1 align=\"center\">AngularFire2</h1>   <p align=\"center\">The official library for Firebase and Angular 2</p> </p>",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/request": "0.0.30",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.10",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "json": "^9.0.3",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-systemjs": "^0.10.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "parse5": "^1.3.2",
    "protractor": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.35.11",
    "rollup-watch": "^2.5.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.16",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.7",
    "traceur": "0.0.96",
    "typedoc": "github:jeffbcross/typedoc",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "ce4f98467c5a8b2cc1dfd607fda718aee8d64521",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/angularfire2/-/angularfire2-2.0.0-beta.7.tgz"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "angular",
    "firebase"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "bundles/angularfire2.umd.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "angularcore",
      "email": "angular-core+npm@google.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "davideast",
      "email": "dceast@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "jeffbcross",
      "email": "middlefloor@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "module": "index.js",
  "name": "angularfire2",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/angular/angularfire2.git"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "version": "2.0.0-beta.7"
}
```

Comment: please don't ask your questions twice! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971144/how-to-return-true-or-false-from-angularfire2-facebook-authentication

Comment: @mxii it's not the same question, that question is asking how to return true or false from a method.  This question is regarding subscribing to auth issue when signing out.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `LoginService`!

And separate login and auth-subscription.

```js
export class LoginService {

   public isLoggedIn = false;
   private _authSubsription;

   constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {
      this._authSubscription = this._af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
         if (!auth) {
            console.log('LOGGED OUT!!');
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
            return;
         }

         this.isLoggedIn = true;

         // do your stuff here ..
      });
   }

   public login() {
      this._af.auth.login({
         provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
         method: AuthMethods.Popup,
         scope: ['public_profile']
      });
   }

   public logout() {
      this._af.auth.logout();
   }
}
```

See my branch: https://github.com/mxii/test-application

And PR: https://github.com/Atkinson88/test-application/pull/1

There is an existing problem with your `LoginService`. Its instantiated twice, I am not sure why.

Comment: I still need to retrieve the facebook Id and access token from auth and authstate so I'm not entirely sure how the above would help ?

Comment: Yes, that's what `do your stuff here` means! :) But be more clean and separate stuff like this.. its an idea, not a working solution.

Comment: I've tried separating the code as you suggested, however the issue I explained still remains.

Comment: Please create a plunker to reproduce it.. it's really hard to get your real problem..

Comment: I've just added a git repo, has loads of issues trying to get this into plunker unfortunately.  The repo consists of a cut down version of the project, see updated question for additional information.

Comment: Any chance you could have a look at the repo?

Comment: Just to confirm, what I'm trying to achieve is have the one login page.  This login page will cater for new signs ups and existing users.  So if the user signs up for the first time and his/hers details do not exists in firebase I then call facebook graph API and retrieve the information about that user i.e first_name, last_name etc.  If the user already exists then don't call the facebook graph API as I've already got the information in the database..

Comment: I've opened a bounty on this, and also added a 'Final Update' to the question outlining what I'm looking for, is this something you could help with @mxii ?

Comment: I've just downloaded you're project, installed the dependancies, the first issue I have is inside the login service > logininwithFacebook method, its saying Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'UserInfo' ? if I change .than(auth => to .than((auth:any) => then the error disappears.  After making that change and running the project I get this error: zone.js:1382 GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/10158174038510346?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email&access_token=null 400 () seems the access token is not being set correctly. ?

Comment: Getting this warning too, but its wrong.. please take a look at the console.. should be an output `fat ..........`.

Comment: Added another commit to my branch, working fine on my side.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, just checked, also it's still producing the same error, when you login and log back in it seems facebookId becomes undefined.

Comment: Whats printed to the console? What version of angularfire2 is installed?

Comment: Just added the error screen shot.  It seems it doesn't keep track of FacebookId as that's what it just failed on, I have your recent code base and the access token seems to be available all the time now.  Just the FacebookId

Comment: Seems like an `angularfire2` problem. Whats your current version? goto `node_modules/angularfire2/package.json`.

Comment: Just added my AngularFire2 package.json to the question.

Comment: `beta.7`, same version on my side.. strange! will add some additional outputs! what browser do you use?

Comment: Currently using chrome, I have noticed though when you sign up and then delete the account through angular fire auth delete method, if you then try and signup again the Facebook Id returned is null.  You basically have to do a hard refresh of the page and then. Click signin with Facebook again to retrieve the Facebook id which I find strange...

Comment: Hows the status? Just working fine for me.. did you changed anything on my branch or just pull and run it?

Comment: I ended up re-writing the whole setup, after seeing some ideas in the code you provided and now it's working as expected, i didn't rely on local storage as much but still the end result is clean and pristine :), either way the 250 rep points will be yours as of later tonight.

Comment: would be great to see your final solution. :)

Comment: I'll make the modifications to the test project / re-upload to git over the weekend and let you know when it's available :)